# Question from Herstein's Topics in Algebra on Sylow subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and suppose that $f$ is an automorphism of $G$ with order 3 that fixes only the identity element of $G$. Show that $G$ has a single (i. e. normal) $p$-Sylow subgroup for each prime $p$ dividing $|G|$.

Been working for hours and haven't made much progress. I did note that since $f$ considered as a permutation factors as the product of disjoint 3-cycles, 3 divides $|G|$. So my next step is showing that the 3-Sylow subgroup is normal.

Edit: sorry, since $f$ fixes the identity it actually factors into a bunch of 3-cycles and a 1-cycle. So 3 does not divide $|G|$.

Comment: This is a duplicate, but I don't have a link handy. Personally I spent hours a day for a week on this problem when I was studying this book and was only able to solve it halfway. For the level of difficulty, a few hours is a drop in the bucket.

Comment: Yikes. Herstein is not playing around. I believe he mentions in the intro that some of the problems are research level.

Comment: Any chance you remember how far you got on the problem and how you managed to do it?

Comment: I came up with this identity that seemed really important, but I didn't know what to do with it. When I finally broke down and asked for help, the algebraist who told me the answer said "Once you find this identity, it's all routine." Sure, routine for him! But I found the identity at least.

Comment: Word, thanks. I hope someone on here can give a full solution because it's a very cool looking result and I don't even know how to begin thinking about it.